# Read file and keep it into 2d list java

Tags: java, exception, text-files, numberformatexception

Here is my text file:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6,7
```

and this is my code snippet:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Findcycle {
    private final static String DELIMITER = ",";
    private final static String filePath = "D:\\1.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File(filePath);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try 
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
            scanner.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {
                String value = scanner.next();
                Integer num = Integer.parseInt(value);
                numbers.add(num);
            }
            System.out.println(numbers);
            scanner.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "3 4"     at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) 
>   at Findcycle.main(Findcycle.java:18)

What should I do?

Comment: "3 4" is not a single number, it's two! So what exactly is the meaning of this one specific entry that is separated by a whitespace instead of a comma? Also where do you have a 2D list in this code?

Comment: This looks like a typo. This ticket can be closed.

Comment: `next()` returns non-delimiter tokens, but if you set delimiter only as `,` you are not including line separators or other whitespaces as part of delimiter. Depending on what you want to achieve you could use delimiter like `",|\\s+"` which is regular expression representing `,` OR `one or more whitespaces`.

Answer (score 1):

Your file has mixing of comma `,` and new line `\n` delimiters.

You should config your scanner to use both delimiters.

Replace this

```
        scanner.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
```

with

```
        scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your String is not well formated as said before.
I thought the whitespace is actually a new line in your code.

So I changed your scanner to a BufferedReader and worked with Streams from there on:

```
private final static String filePath = "D:\\1.txt";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputFile = new File(filePath);
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[,\\s]+");
        rd.lines().forEach(x-> Arrays.asList(pattern.split(x)).forEach(y->numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(y))));
        rd.close();
        System.out.println(numbers);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Pretty neat that line, isn't it?

PS: I added the answer before, so if your whitespace is a whitespace, it will still compile the numbers correctly